# WP8 In-App purchase testing

Tags: windows-phone-7, in-app-purchase, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I followed this guide here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#IAP_MockService to set a IIS service for in-app purchase testing, but when I try to open `http://localhost/v8/help` I am getting the message bellow

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     DirectoryListingModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL

```
http://localhost:80/v8/help/
```

Physical Path      C:\IapcatalogMockService\CatalogServiceMock\v8\help\
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

Anybody knows what is wrong ?

I will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the some problem.
Then solved by use source code to rebuild the website and re-deploy.
Some time, after re-deploy it show config section error, you can just remove the config section in web.config file.
It works for me.